# What's the chemical equation for the lithium iron phosphate battery

Tags: everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry

The title says it all, I'm searching for the chemical equation to the lithium iron phosphate battery.

I know that the cathode is made of $\ce{LiFePO4}$ and that upon discharging, it is transformed to $\ce{FePO4}$. The Anode is made of graphite.

So I think that the reaction on the anode is:
$\ce{LiFePO4 -> FePO4 + Li+ + e-}$

Is this correct? If so, what's happening on the anode?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60437

Answer (score 1):

Close, the cathode reaction is:

$$ \ce{LiFePO4 -> FePO4 + Li^+ + e^-}$$

The anode is:

$$\ce{Li^+ + C6 + e^- -> LiC6}$$

The best description I can give is that the lithium ion intercalates into the graphite and "steals" some electron density from the six-membered conjugated ring.

Comment: Just to clarify, we call the LFP/FP electrode the "cathode" regardless of whether it's charging/discharging. It's sloppy terminology but that's the way the it is.